# Работа с реестром

Tags: c#, реестр

Есть такой код:

```
String kompasPath = @"SOFTWARE\ASCON\KOMPAS-3D";
String[] keyNames = null;

// Определение разрядности операционной системы.
Boolean is64System = Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem;

RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(kompasPath);
...
```

Путь правильный, но key получает null. Система 64, приложение компилится Any CPU.

В чём дело?

Comment: Ну как минимум не ясно что у вас в searchPath... Попутно укажите разрядность системы и приложения, из которого этот код работает.

Comment: может у вас банальная опечатка? `kompasPath` - `searchPath`

Comment: Поправил вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
using (var hklm = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine,
                                          RegistryView.Registry32)) // или Registry64
using (var key = hklm.OpenSubKey(kompasPath))
{
    // ваш код
}
```

Судя по всему, ваше приложение 32-битное, а программа 64-битная, вот она и видит 64-битную версию реестра.

---

У 64-разрядных и 32-разрядных программ разный «вид» на реестр. Если программа, которая писала в реестр, и программа, которая читала из него, одинаковой разрядности, то всё будет работать и без трюков, с использованием `Registry.LocalMachine` (при этом обе программы будут обращаться к версии реестра для своей разрядности). Но если разрядность может быть разная, нужно при открытии реестра точно указывать, какую именно из версий реестра вы хотите обрабатывать.

Comment: Получается, это будет работать только на системе указанной разрядности?

Comment: Всё верно, попробовал скомпилить под 64, заработало.

Comment: @Сергей: Дополнил ответ.